# Select and order nearest date match with multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

First off, I'm not sure if SQL is even the route I should take for most of this as I'm fairly new to it but here goes:

I have a database with multiple columns of dates and, without going over, I'd like to grab the rows with the closest corresponding date in order.
I'm then displaying the information with PHP.

Hopefully this will explain what I'm after:

```
c_date = 0001/01/01;

e_id |  e_date_1  |  e_date_2  |  e_date_3
--------------------------------------------
  0  | 0001/01/02 | 0001/01/15 | 0001/02/02
--------------------------------------------
  1  | 0001/01/08 | 0001/01/12 | 0001/01/17 
--------------------------------------------
  2  | 0001/01/02 | 0001/01/13 | 0001/02/12 
--------------------------------------------
  3  | 0000/12/29 | 0001/01/01 | 0001/02/12
--------------------------------------------
  4  | 0001/01/24 | 0001/02/01 | 0001/02/12
```

0.1 & 2.1 are closest in the first column, but 3.2 is closer than 0.2 making 3 selection #1
0.1 & 2.1 are the same, but 2.2 is closer than 0.2 making 2 selection #2
etc

Final:
**3, 2, 0, 1, 4**

Can anyone help me in the right direction? I've been going through manuals and tutorials but nothing seems to offer a solution to what I'm looking for.
Maybe I'm going about storing the data the wrong way? I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does `0.1` mean?  What formula defines "closeness"?

Comment: Generally, any time you have enumerated columns, it's time to rethink your design

Answer (score 1):

The logic of your desired data selection is not clear to me, but almost without a doubt whatever it is you're trying to do could be done more easily if the data are in a normalized form.

If you can store the data in a different structure, as you imply, then you should normalize the data structure by using a single column to store identifiers corresponding to your different date columns.  Such a table would be defined like this:

create table e_dates (
   e_id integer,
   e_date_id integer,
   e_date date
   );

The first row of your current table would correspond to three rows in this normalized table, with values:
   (0, 1, 0001/01/02)
   (0, 2, 0001/01/15)
   (0, 3, 0001/01/15)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select e_id
from ((select e_id, e_date_1 as e_date from t) union all
      (select e_id, e_date_2 as e_date from t) union all
      (select e_id, e_date_3 as e_date from t)
     ) t
group by e_id
order by min(abs(datediff(c_date, d_date));
```

This returns the `e_id`s based on the nearest of the three dates.